# Does memcpy depend on the type of the source and destination pointers?

Tags: c++, linux, memcpy

This code,

```
uint32_t length;
BYTE* message;
printf("Inspecting message with length %d and contents: ", length);
for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
    printf("%d ", message[i]);
printf("\n");
....
char* outbuff;
outbuff = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * length + sizeof(int));
uint32_t data_length = htonl(length);
memcpy(outbuff, &data_length , sizeof(int));
memcpy(outbuff + sizeof(uint32_t), message, length);

printf("Sending  outbuff over network with length %d and contents: ", length);
for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
    printf("%d ", outbuff[i]);
printf("\n");
```

doesn't faithfully copy data from message and length to outbuff. But as soon as I change the type of outbuff from char* to BYTE*, it works fine.

Any idea why it behaves so? The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Copying-Strings-and-Arrays.html) doesn't help in this matter.

EDIT.1: Changed `&length` to `&data_length`. I manually typed the code instead of copying in SX.

EDIT.2: Code to print out the BYTE array.

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't "faithfully copy data from message and length"? How do you verify what was copied?

Comment: This code is messy. Why `sizeof(int)` when length is `uint32_t`? Why do you assign to `data_length` but copy `length`?

Comment: A potential unrelated bug is that you copy `sizeof(int)` bytes of an object that is not necessarily `int`. When copying a uint32_t, you should copy `sizeof(uint32_t)` bytes.

Comment: OT: `sizeof(char)` is [guaranteed to by 1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sizeof#1.sentence-4).

Comment: (1) `sizeof(char)` is always 1 and hence can be omitted. (2) @eerorika is right: Use `uint32_t` throughout for the length, especially for `sizeof`: There is no guarantee that `int` is 32 bit. (3) `memcpy()` will work no matter what the type of the first pointer is. (But you must take care when you add to it, as in `outbuff + sizeof(uint32_t)`, because if it points to  a type whose size is >1 you will arrive at the wrong address. This should not matter here since `BYTE` is typically a typedef for `unsigned char`.)

Comment: `BYTE` doesn't exist, but wherever you got it from surely makes it a, er, byte, which is also what `char` is.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica It's a Windows thing, and is an `unsigned char`. So I'm guessing the problem is a signed/unsigned integer conversion thing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude A signed/unsigned conversion which compromises the data somewhere unrelated to the `memcpy`..

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Yes, which is why I asked how the OP verified the data. It's probably there that the signed/unsigned problem lies.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude There is a `BYTE` in Windows, yes. This one could be from something else. Do note, in particular, the [tag:linux] tag. Point is we don't know and guessing is counterproductive.

Comment: Let me add another iteration of the standard request to the OP: **Please provide a minimal working example** which exposes your problem. This standing request has two reasons: (1) It obviously helps us see where the problem is, not least because often the problem is not where the OP *thinks* it is. (2) In the process of assembling the minimal example the OP will often detect the error themselves; it is a prime error finding strategy even for experienced programmers. For example you will find here that **memcpy works fine with signed and unsigned chars alike.** The error is elsewhere.

Comment: I took the liberty of changing the question title, turning the underlying assumption into a question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I'm printing all bytes in that array using printf("%d").

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica, true.. BYTE is a windows type, but I had to use BYTE because SecuGen Fingerprint scanner API for Linux uses windows typedefs including DWORD and BYTE etc.

Comment: @VineetMenon Please *show* us how you do it, add it as part of your [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

I'm answering the new title question which I just edited in myself ;-).

The answer is a simple *No.*

The link in your question shows that `memcpy()`is declared as `void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);`. Both pointer parameters are void pointers.

The standard draft lists conversions of any pointer to `void *` as a *standard conversion* (which does not need an explicit cast). [Specifically, it states](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.ptr) (emphasis by me):

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv T”, where T is an object type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv void”. **The pointer value ([basic.compound]) is unchanged by this conversion.**

This means that any object pointer you throw at it will be converted to a numerically identical void pointer before memcpy even sees it, and hence be treated identically.

Your problem must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing here but I think you meant to use network byte ordering, hence the `data_length` attribution, but after it you still put the `length` into the buffer instead.

Your

```
memcpy(outbuff, &length, sizeof(int));
```

should have probably read

```
memcpy(outbuff, &data_length, sizeof(uint32_t));
```

Also you seem to be using `int` and `uint32_t` interchangeably. They're not, even on platforms where the size matches the one is signed while the other one is unsigned.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks for the suggestion. I did indeed copied data_length instead of length. It was a typo as explained in the EDIT to my question.

Comment: I have to insist on what Peter already asked from you, that is to provide a minimal example of what is actually happening... from what I can tell, as well as others have expressed, this should work now... Provide a minimal example of it not working, the error might be in your networking code or somewhere else

Comment: I have already edited my question to satisfy your request. Garbling of array elements occur much before I start sending data over network.

Comment: No, @Vineet, you haven't. You were already given a link to instructions on how to make a [mcve]. Please follow it, read them, and do it!

Answer (score 0):

Doing `memcpy()` from `BYTE*` to `char*` may lead to wrap around range of `char` i.e. -127 to 127 due to `BYTE` being unsigned from 0 to 255.

For example, suppose we have:

```
BYTE uchArr[] = {12, 129, 250};
BYTE * ptr_uchArr = (BYTE*) malloc (sizeof(BYTE)*3);
memcpy(ptr_uchArr, &uchArr, sizeof(BYTE)*3);
//ptr_uchArr shall be {12, 129, 250} as intended...
```

And now we want to perform `memcpy()` from `BYTE*` to `char*`

```
char * ptr_chArr = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*3);
memcpy(ptr_chArr, ptr_uchArr, sizeof(BYTE)*3);
//ptr_chArr shall be {12, -127, -6} as a result of wrap around...
```

What if we perform the reverse i.e. `memcpy()` from `char*` to  `BYTE*`:

```
memcpy(ptr_uchArr, ptr_chArr, sizeof(BYTE)*3);
//ptr_uchArr shall still be {12, 129, 250} as intended again as a result of wrap around...
```

Comment: No, `memcpy` copies the data in the bytes. That's it. How you later _interpret_ those bytes is unimportant to `memcpy`. It is true, however, that there is a possible problem with said interpretation when the target type isn't what the OP wanted.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I agree!!